# Meaning of ベタベタ when referring to a meeting

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension, onomatopoeia

Referring to the Tanabata lovers who only meet once a year:

> A) 「せめて毎月一回会えればいいのに」
>   A) "I wish they could meet at least once a month."
>   B) 「一年一回っていうのがいいんだ。そんなに何回もベタベタ会うもんじゃねェや」
>   B) "Once a year is fine. In that way they'll meet *stickily* many times. Right?"

What on earth does ベタベタ mean in this context? I thought it meant sticky. But I can't imagine what a sticky meeting is.

Comment: None of these meanings fit the context? http://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%99%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%82%BF

Comment: @siikamiika Well I think "clinging (e.g. of a person)" might be relevant somehow, but I really can't get any sensible meaning out of the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ベタベタ is an onomatopoeia (擬態語) commonly used for describing a couple or lovers being close and intimate, as well as for something being sticky. Maybe it's a bit close to イチャイチャ.

> 一年一回っていうのがいいんだ。そんなに何回もベタベタ会うもんじゃねェや
>   (≂ そんなに何回もベタベタ**と**会うものではない)

I think it'd be something like "It's good because it's just once a year. (≂ What's good about it is that they meet only once a year.) They shouldn't be meeting that often (≂ so many times a year), so intimately."

Answer (score 2):

> そんなに何回もベタベタ合うもんじゃねェや

The essence of the above sentence is

> 何回もベタベタ会｛あ｝う

何回もベタベタ会う
＝何回も会う＋ベタベタ会う
＝何回も会う＋ベタベタした感｛かん｝じで会う

In this context "あっさり" is the antonym of "ベタベタ" in Japanese.
We say "彼｛かれ｝と彼女｛かのじょ｝の関係｛かんけい｝はあっさりしている。" to describe their indifferent relation.
Do you get the nuance of "ベタベタした感じ"?

Comment: I think the problem is understanding how meeting (合う) can be ベタベタ. It comes naturally to native Japanese people, but I also think it sounds a bit strange. How do you understand the relation of 何回も and ベタベタ? Are they both adverbs modifying 合う or is そんなに何回も separate from ベタベタ合う?

Comment: @siikamiika You've described my problem exactly.

Comment: @mackygoo So might 'passionately' be a suitable translation of  ベタベタ? If they meet once a year their meeting will be passionate, but if they meet every month then it will be less intense? Is that the kind of meaning?

Comment: @mackygoo I'm not sure if そんなに is talking about person A or person B's previous comment. If it refers to person A then I might think he means that meeting once a month is too much, and meeting too often makes the relationship 'sticky' in a bad way. I'm very confused.

Comment: @ user3856370  >'passionately'  Yes, it is suitable. But the latter understanding is incorrect. They are too passionate to be in normal passion, which could not make them apart for a year.

Comment: ベタベタした感じで makes a bit more sense to me. Btw, I noticed that in the question the kanji 合 is used instead of 会 but the meaning is the same in this case I suppose?

Comment: @siikamiika Sorry, that was a typo. I just fixed it.

Comment: @mackygoo I'm really sorry but I still don't understand. Could you give your translation of the full sentence please?

Comment: user3856370 Yes, そんなに is talking about person A's previous comment of meeting once a month. 
To make your confusion clear, I have two questions. 
- Is "B) そんなに何回もベタベタ合うもんじゃねェや」" B's comment? 
- Who is "he" in the sentence "If it refers to person A then I might think he means that meeting once a month is too much" ?

Comment: @mackygoo I edited the question so it looks like the original text. 'He' is person B. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

It feels to me that ベタベタ here is *not* describing a manner in which single instances of Orihime and Hikoboshi's meeting may be engaged in. Rather, by ベタベタ Person B is referring to the frequency with which, Person A wishes, they could see each other. Person B thinks meeting once a month would be to "ベタベタ会う", regardless of how "clinglingly" the star-crossed lovers might spend their time together. (Person A mentions only how often they should meet, not in what way, don' they? Then it would be somewhat incongruous with the anaphoric そんな if we interpret ベタベタ as a "manner adverb", unless Person B is somehow presupposing that the meeting would be ベタベタ in the "manner" sense of the word, which I think is unlikely.)